# multiple direction slider on click

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am looking for a plugin or a script which will do the following:

When a button is clicked an image will slide in from outside(right) of the div.

The next time it is clicked another image will slide in from the top of the div.

this will repeat until there are no longer any images to be displayed.

I have searched everywhere and can not find anything like this, and so far have nothing to work with

Comment: Your request is rather unique. I wouldn't expect to find a untility to do exactly that. Find a slider you like and implement a simple counter to change the slide direction. If you need help with that, post specific questions after you've made some effort.

Comment: Thanks For your reply. I have had little experience with sliders, I usually use bxslider in my sites. Would you implement the counter in the same place as where you would call the slider?

Comment: You'd probably have to modify the core bxslider files to get that effect.

Comment: Here's an example ive been working on:   http://www.luvly.co.nz/space/waikanae-beach-house.html.  if you use the left and right arrows it does exactly what im wanting. Would you please be able to help me with the counter so it does both of these from one arrow direction or click?

Comment: I'm happy to take a look, but I get a JS error alert and no buttons on that page.

Comment: Im trying to just get it going through the arrow keys at the moment. @isherwood

$slider = $('#slider').rhinoslider({ slideNextDirection: 'toTop', callBackNext: function() { $(this).slideNextDirection = 'toLeft'; //tried this too :) //$slider.slideNextDirection = 'toLeft'; return false; } });

Here is what i have tried however still not working.

Comment: Please put code in your question and use code formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Just stumbled on this post, and created a quick pen to illustrate what I *envisioned* you describing... Maybe a day late and a dollar short (just noticed the date of the original post) but here it is nonetheless;
http://cdpn.io/FAkuE

Comment: You should include at least the jist of the answer (if not everything) in your _answer_. External links can go stale and make your post worthless.

Answer (score -1):

A Carousel is what you are looking for, you may have to adjust the animation to get it to slide from the top. try http://www.tripwiremagazine.com/2012/12/jquery-carousel.html

Comment: I don't see how this offers alternating side direction.

Comment: I'm going to try using this slider:  http://flexslider.woothemes.com/index.html  It has multi directional slides so just need to figure out where to change the animatition or add the counter